# Kotlin for Android - Kotlin programming

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am a bigginer learning Kotlin for android I start creating a little app in my learning journey and my question is:

**1- If I use the following method to create an array of image and to call it:**

var Images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.PHGLHB_356, R.drawable.PHGLFY145,R.drawable.basket10,R.drawable.basket2,R.drawable.basket3)

var index_image = 0

**What can I do to do the same when I want to create a list of string please?**

var Textes = ArrayList(R.string.text1,R.string.text2,R.string.text3,R.string.text4,R.string.text5)

var index_text = 0

**2- Also I have the following function to set the image source (Below is the code I try):**

```
fun ChangeImage(view: View){
    var image_view = findViewById(R.id.image_view) as ImageView
    image_view.setImageResource(Images[index_image])
    index_image++

    if (index_image == Images.size){

        index_image = 0
    }
}
```

**3-How to do for getting the text (Below is the code I try):**

```
fun ChangeText(view: TextView) {
        var text_view = findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView
        text_view.setText(Textes[index_text])
        index_text++

        if (index_text == Textes.size) {

            index_text = 0
        }
}
```

**Thank you for your precious help guys!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array:

```
var Images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.PHGLHB_356, R.drawable.PHGLFY145,R.drawable.basket10,R.drawable.basket2,R.drawable.basket3)
```

is not an array of images but an array of integers corresponding to the ids of drawables.
Similarly this array list (if it was initialized properly):

```
var Textes = ArrayList(R.string.text1,R.string.text2,R.string.text3,R.string.text4,R.string.text5)
```

is not an array list of strings but an array of integers corresponding to the ids of strings stored in resources. 
So you could use `intArrayOf` instead of `ArrayList` just like the other array, as this way is more Kotlin-like:

```
var Textes = intArrayOf(R.string.text1,R.string.text2,R.string.text3,R.string.text4,R.string.text5)
```

Both your functions are syntactically correct although it's better to write the `findViewById()` method like this:

```
var image_view = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view)
```

and

```
var text_view = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)
```

Also you don't even need to use `findViewById()` if you have in your imports a line like this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

if you do then you can access `image_view` and `text_view` without finding them with `findViewById()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. You are the best and I want to let you know that I follow your advice and the app work fine. Thank you so much again dear friend. Just learn new thing by using the best way : var image_view = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view).

Comment: By the way, after importing the line like this: import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main, How to write the code if I don't need to use findViewById() ?

Comment: If your code is inside the activity class and the view's id is `text_view` then you can use `text_view` anywhere in that class without the need of  doing `findViewById()`. So `text_view.setText(Textes[index_text])` is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much forpas